# Java - how to add gui which will make use of initial classes

Tags: java, jbutton

I've written a standard console application (web scraping) with several classes. The only thing that main fucntion does, is: 
- create one instance of a class
- call one method from created object

Now I need to add the simplest GUI which will contain one button to perform second of those aforementioned actions (call method) and textarea to display everything that NetBeans output shows now.

I created new file with GUI class. It's basically a jFrame with jButton and jTextArea. I managed to get text output to work like I assumed. However I have no idea how to set the button. Netbeans creator redirects me to this part of code:

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    p1.use(); // <<< my initial try
}
```

where p1 is object created in main class in original file. Netbeans marks "p1" as "cannot find symbol" which is understandable. However, how can I perform such a simple operation? I basically need that Button to push the program forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the p1 object from your main class into the class for your GUI through a constructor or setter, otherwise it doesn't know what you're trying to access.

For example,

```
public class MainClass {
    private MyGuiClass gui;
    private P1Class    p1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p1  = new P1Class( /*arguments*/ );
        gui = new MyGuiClass( p1, /*other arguments*/ );
    }
    // Other logic...
}

public class MyGuiClass extends JFrame {
    private P1Class p1;
    public MyGuiClass( P1Class p1, /*other arguments*/ ) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }
    // Other logic...
}
```

At this point, you can refer to the p1 object in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you. How could I not think about it before... However, there comes the question - what if I need to create object in main after GUI class is constructed. Call some setter from GUI to pass the object? But then I think I would need to declare it before running application. Maybe declaring ArrayList<Class> would be a solution? Then the constructor and additional setter would be able to capture any amount of objects at any time and make some kind of a stack. Am I following right track?

Comment: Unless you plan to use more than one of the P1 class, you shouldn't need an ArrayList. If the GUI class must be declared before the P1 class, you can add an action listener to the button as part of the setter. In the setter, you'd have `this.p1 = p1;`, then

`buttonName.addActionListener( 
    new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
            p1.use(); 
        } 
    }
);`

Comment: Thanks. That was theoretical question. And I meant that particular situation: one object is created before GUI class instance, but then, during the run-time there's a need to create more objects. Like this: p1  = new P1Class( /*arguments*/ ); gui = new MyGuiClass( p1, /*other arguments*/ ); p2  = new P1Class( /*arguments*/ ); gui.set(p2); However I imagine that once the GUI instance is created in main class, there will be no further operations in main as all handling goes to the GUI and user, so the mentioned example has no use. Is that assumption right?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that.

**Scenario 1**

Make the object p1 accessible to the jFrame object by making it static in the Main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static P1 p1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p1 = new P1();
        //open window etc.
    }
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Access object by static reference
        Main.p1.use();
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

You can pass the object `P1` as a parameter to the constructor of your jFrame object.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P1 p1 = new P1();
        new MyFrame(p1);
        //open window etc.
    }
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private P1 p1;

    public MyFrame(P1 param) {
        // Save object inside the JFrame object
        this.p1 = param;
    }

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        p1.use();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have heard that static objects or variables aren't the best habit, especially for beginners, but nontheless it is a solution indeed. Thank you for samples.

Comment: You're right, the second solution is probably the way to go, I just listed 2 options. You also have the option to make P1 a singleton so you can access it from everywhere, but then again it depends if the class P1 really is suited for such a use.